# Why is Big Query creating a new column instead of joining two columns when using a Join?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, inner-join

When I use a Join in BigQuery, it completes it but creates a new column which are named Id_1 and Date_1 with the same information from the primary key. What could cause this? Here is the code.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.daily_Activity`
JOIN
  `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.sleep_day`
ON
  `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.daily_Activity`.Id = `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.sleep_day`.Id
  AND `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.daily_Activity`.Date = `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.sleep_day`.Date
```

I made the query and expected the tables to join by the Primary keys of `Id` and `Date`, but instead this created two new columns with the same information.

Comment: SELECT * with a JOIN ON will give you both tables' all columns. You can do JOIN USING instead if you only want one Id and one Date column.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `*` in the *select list* the `ON` variant of a `JOIN` clause produces all columns from both tables in the result set. If there are columns with the same name on both sides, then both will show up in the result [with slightly different names] as you can see.

You can use the `USING` variant of the `JOIN` clause instead, that *merges* the columns and produces only one resulting column for each column mentioned in the `USING` clause. This is probably what you want. See [BigQuery - INNER JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#inner_join).

Your query could take the form:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.daily_Activity`
JOIN
  `bellabeat-case-study-373821.bellabeat_case_study.sleep_day`
USING (Id, Date)
```

**Note**: `USING` can only be used when the columns you want to join with have the exact same name. It won't be possible to use it if a column is, for example, called `id` in one table and `employee_id` in the other one.